# Cannot split path using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, cypher

I am trying to split a Cypher path which looks like this:

```
(`GROUP1`: TRAVEL_PLAN { name: 'GROUP1' })-[:_USE_]->(`LODGING`: TRAVEL_ENTITLEMENT { name: 'LODGING' })-[:_HAVE_]->(`LODGING_R_1`: RULE { name: 'LODGING_R_1' })-[:_ENTITLE_TO_]->(`RS 3000`: MONEY { name: 'RS 3000' })
```

Which after splitting should give me where the elements at even indices are the nodes in parenthesis and the elements in the odd indices are the relation combining them in square brackets:

```
(`GROUP1`: TRAVEL_PLAN { name: 'GROUP1' })
[:_USE_]
(`LODGING`: TRAVEL_ENTITLEMENT { name: 'LODGING' })
[:_HAVE_]
(`LODGING_R_1`: RULE { name: 'LODGING_R_1' })
[:_ENTITLE_TO_]
(`RS 3000`: MONEY { name: 'RS 3000' })
```

---

**My attempt 1:**

```
public static void Main()
{
        string input = @"(`GROUP1`: TRAVEL_PLAN { name: 'GROUP1' })-[:_USE_]->(`LODGING`: TRAVEL_ENTITLEMENT { name: 'LODGING' })-[:_HAVE_]->(`LODGING_R_1`: RULE { name: 'LODGING_R_1' })-[:_ENTITLE_TO]->(`RS 3000`: MONEY { name: 'RS 3000' })";
        string pattern = @"(\(.+\))-(\[.+\])->(\(.+\))";
        string [] split = input.Split(new[] { "-", "->" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (string item in split)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Which outputs me (notice the `>` in the beginning of some entries):

```
(`GROUP1`: TRAVEL_PLAN { name: 'GROUP1' })
[:_USE_]
>(`LODGING`: TRAVEL_ENTITLEMENT { name: 'LODGING' })
[:_HAVE_]
>(`LODGING_R_1`: RULE { name: 'LODGING_R_1' })
[:_ENTITLE_TO]
>(`RS 3000`: MONEY { name: 'RS 3000' })
```

**My attempt 2:**

```
public static void Main()
{
        string input = @"(`GROUP1`: TRAVEL_PLAN { name: 'GROUP1' })-[:_USE_]->(`LODGING`: TRAVEL_ENTITLEMENT { name: 'LODGING' })-[:_HAVE_]->(`LODGING_R_1`: RULE { name: 'LODGING_R_1' })-[:_ENTITLE_TO]->(`RS 3000`: MONEY { name: 'RS 3000' })";
        string pattern = @"(\(.+\))-(\[.+\])->(\(.+\))";
        string[] regSplit = Regex.Split(input, pattern);

        foreach (string item in regSplit)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Which outputs me:

```
(`GROUP1`: TRAVEL_PLAN { name: 'GROUP1' })-[:_USE_]->(`LODGING`: TRAVEL_ENTITLEMENT { name: 'LODGING' })-[:_HAVE_]->(`LODGING_R_1`: RULE { name: 'LODGING_R_1' })
[:_ENTITLE_TO]
(`RS 3000`: MONEY { name: 'RS 3000' })
```

(This is my current [`Regex`](https://regex101.com/r/sIYEkZ/2))

I am scratching my head for a long time for this, will appreciate if anybody could help.

Comment: Isn't there parsers already existing ?

Comment: @Cid No its a Cypher query path, and I want to extract the nodes and relations from the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your split pattern can be:

```
(?<=\))-|(?<=\])->
```

which translates to:

- `(?<=\))-` find all `-` chars which are preceded by a `)`
- `|` or
- `(?<=\])->` find all `->` sequences which are preceded by a `]`

and it will produce:

```
(`GROUP1`: TRAVEL_PLAN { name: 'GROUP1' })
[:_USE_]
(`LODGING`: TRAVEL_ENTITLEMENT { name: 'LODGING' })
[:_HAVE_]
(`LODGING_R_1`: RULE { name: 'LODGING_R_1' })
[:_ENTITLE_TO_]
(`RS 3000`: MONEY { name: 'RS 3000' })
```

Comment: Split by positive lookbehind ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are over complicating it. Try this:

```
 string input = @"(`GROUP1`: TRAVEL_PLAN { name: 'GROUP1' })-[:_USE_]->(`LODGING`: TRAVEL_ENTITLEMENT { name: 'LODGING' })-[:_HAVE_]->(`LODGING_R_1`: RULE { name: 'LODGING_R_1' })-[:_ENTITLE_TO]->(`RS 3000`: MONEY { name: 'RS 3000' })";
 string[] split = input.Split(new[] { '-', '>' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
 foreach (string item in split)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(item);
 }

 Console.ReadKey();
```

Notice the simplified split characters and no need for regex at this point.

Comment: What if a `-` or `>` appears in the value strings? `'GROUP1'` could easily be `'GROUP-1'`.

Comment: @JuanR that is a good point. I just went off of the example string. I up voted the excepted answer.

Comment: It's all good. I would think the "proper" way of doing this would be to write a language parser but Regex works when a quick and dirty solution is needed.